# JDBC Driver Templates in Red Hat Developer Studio 12

Tags: java, eclipse, redhat, jboss-developer-studio

I cannot find any JDBC driver templates in the latest Redhat Developer Studio version 12.0.0.GA. Anyone else having the same issue? Even trying to actually use the Generic driver template isn't really working. Environment is Windows 10. I uninstalled and deleted the .metadata directory but nothing helps. I copied a older set of xml files for .plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity but then I get a null pointer exception when trying to open anything but the generic driver. Anyone NOT getting this error?

[image]

Comment: Is the "JAR List" tab available there? Can you add jars on said tab?

Comment: Yea, I can add jars and even create a "generic driver" data source but then that data source doesn't let me add any connections to the data explorer. So it's not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround exists for:

- devstudio 12.0 / [DTP 1.14.100 for Photon 2018-06](http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/1.14.100.201805031905/repository/) and
- devstudio 12.9 / [DTP 1.14.102 for Simrel 2018-09](http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/updates/1.14.102.201809101906/repository/) users.

a) Help > Install new software > add the [appropriate URL for the compatible DTP site](https://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php) (or use the links above)

b) select enablement features > install

c) restart when prompted

Solution will be in the studio 12.10 release - see [this JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-4731) for updates.